# C++ Pointer to struct member

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, memory-address

If I were to make a struct, say:

```
struct FOO{    
    int x, y, z, a, b, c;  
}

int main(){  
    FOO foo = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};        

    return 0;
}
```

Would there be anyway to create a pointer that can access FOO's integer members?
Maybe by making pointer that points to foo and then somehow modifying it to increment in integers?

I know that if I were to make FOO a class instead with a method that returns a pointer to the first int, then I could cycle though the members with ++ or [i](in a for loop). But I want to know if I can access structure members simply by knowing the address of the struct (assuming I have a good understanding of how to navigate said struct)

Any insight would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Not without some type of reflection, no. With any luck, it'll be possible in a few years.

Comment: As Nikola pointed out, the difference between class and struct that you mention doesn't exist, so if your solution involving a class is sufficiently good for you, it will also be when using a struct. However, I'm wondering what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I'm mostly just trying to increase my understanding/capacity of pointers. I'd like to know how to manipulate data from a "lower level" by maneuvering though memory address's rather than accessing a member directly. But I'm starting to think what I want can't be done in C++

Comment: @Wimp, It sure can, as some of the answers below describe (just in case you haven't seen my other comment, [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24a5fcd62cdfa643)), but not portably.

Answer (score 4):

You can overload operator[] for the struct:

```
struct bar // ALL_UPPERCASE is for macros!
{
    int a, b, c, d, e, f;
    int operator[](size_t i) const
    {
        switch(i)
        {
        case 0: return a;
        case 1: return b;
        case 2: return c;
        case 3: return d;
        case 4: return e;
        case 5: return f;
        default: assert(false);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I'm still trying to find a way to access the members without adding code to the struct itself (if there is such a way).

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought and this might not work, but you could try doing a pointer to the foo struct and then shifting the pointer by the size of an int for each element. So something like:

```
    int * ptr= & foo;
    ptr++;
```

If I'm remembering my hardware design class well enough a struct is actually really similar to an array in memory it can just have variable sized blocks of memory for each of its indices.

Comment: That was my first shot. The pointer tries to increment to the next foo(there isn't any) rather than it's members.

Comment: @Wimp, The difference is that this is a `int *`, so it would increment by `int`, but there's still padding and stuff that the compiler can throw in on a whim.

Comment: Darn compilers ruining everything. Ah well maybe with enough compiler flags? That said, pointer casting is pretty sketch/hacky and definitely not an ideal solution. Probably going to have to wait like chris suggests.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straightforward:

```
Foo foo = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
int* pfoo = &foo.x;

int structMembers = sizeof(Foo) / sizeof(int);
for (int i = 0; i < structMembers; i++)
{
    cout << pfoo[i] << endl;
}
```

There's no difference between a struct and class aside from default access modifier (private in structs, public in classes). Thus whatever you can do with classes, you can do with structs.

Comment: This is still undefined behaviour and you aren't guaranteed to have it work.

Comment: Which line causes undefined behaviour?

Comment: `cout << pfoo[i] << endl;` every time except for the first.

Comment: Would you elaborate? Members are all ints, there's so there's no memory alignment. Structs place their members sequentially in memory, so aren't we guaranteed to find the `i`th member at `pfoo + i`?

Comment: This is definitely the closest solution, but in order the use it, I would have to know that x is a member and that it is the first member. I guess what I'm really wondering is if I could take the the address of foo (0028FDF0 for example) and then tell the pointer to point to the next point of physical memory (incrementing in ints)?

Comment: @NikolaDimitroff, In practicality, I would expect it to [work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5fe09ed0848788d) in common implementations, even [using the object itself](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24a5fcd62cdfa643). Strictly speaking, because they're not in the same array object, taking `pfoo[i]` as `*(pfoo + i)`, even the addition would be undefined behaviour for every `i` except 0 or 1. I would hazard that it might have been considered okay for structures containing continuous elements of the same type, but it's too nuanced in terms of padding and that specific condition alone.

Comment: the order of members between access modifiers is not defined by the standard

Answer (score 1):

```
struct FOO{    
    int x, y, z, a, b, c;  
} __attribute__ ((packed))

FOO foo;
int *i = &foo;
```

In this case, the **attribute** ((packed)) eliminates the problem created by padding, since it get's rid of it. Afterwards incrementing i, grantees that it will be in the next element of the struct.

Answer (score -2):

As I understood you need this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn

if you need own implementation take this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
  int a = 1;
  char b = 'a';
};

template<typename Struct, typename var_type>
const var_type member_get( Struct& obj, var_type Struct::* mem_var ) { return 
obj.*mem_var; }

int main() 
{
  Foo x;
  std::cout << member_get( x, &Foo::a ) << std::endl;
  std::cout << member_get( x, &Foo::b ) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```